# redirect cmd output to a rich textbox text realtime

Tags: c#

when I tried using Arguments :

```
console.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ping -t google.co.id";
```

it works. Ping output appears in richtextbox.

but when I tried using this Argument:

```
console.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c C:\\Plink\\Plink.exe -v -C -N -D 1080 -P 443 myuser@123.123.123 -pw mypassword";
```

rich textbox doesn't displays anything.
but when i checked task manager, i saw that Plink already running.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace output_cmd
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        delegate void UpdateConsoleWindowDelegate(String msg);
        Process console = null;
        StreamWriter consoleStreamWriter = null;

        private void btnCreateConsole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            console = new Process();
            console.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            console.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c C:\\Plink\\Plink.exe -v -C -N -D 1080 -P 443 myuser@123.123.123 -pw mypassword";
            console.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            console.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            console.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);
            console.Start();
            consoleStreamWriter = console.StandardInput;
            console.BeginOutputReadLine();
            console.BeginErrorReadLine();
            btnCreateConsole.Enabled = false;
        }


        private void btnTerminate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!console.HasExited)
            {
                console.Kill();
                console.Dispose();
                console = null;
                btnCreateConsole.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void UpdateConsoleWindow(String message)
        {
            if (txtConsoleWindow.InvokeRequired)
            {
                UpdateConsoleWindowDelegate update = new UpdateConsoleWindowDelegate(UpdateConsoleWindow);
                txtConsoleWindow.Invoke(update, message);
            }
            else
            {
                txtConsoleWindow.AppendText(message);
            }
        }

        private void ConsoleOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
            DataReceivedEventArgs recieved)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(recieved.Data))
            {
                UpdateConsoleWindow(recieved.Data + "\r\n");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

How can i fix this?

update : sorry i wrong write directory separator here :D
but this is still does not fix my issue

Comment: Are you positive that `plink.exe` writes to `stdout`? If it writes to the console using other methods (e.g., `WriteConsole()`) the output won't be redirected to your application

Comment: It is because putty command are strange guys: they write into stderr instead of stdout for normal messages. You can fix your code, adding handler to stdout (checked)
 
`console.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);
console.ErrorDataReceived  += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);
console.Start();`

Comment: thanks Vitaly Golubs you are right plink using sdterr not sdtout now my problem is solved :D